# how to find common letters between shortest and longest word in a sentence, string in C

Tags: c

i have code for find longest and shortest word in sentence. but how to find common letters in 
this 2 words(what to add to the program?)? In C

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h> 

int main() {

  long int i=0,j=0,k=0,a,minIndex=0,maxIndex=0,max=0,min=0;
  char str1[100]={0},substr[100][100]={0};

  printf("Enter a sentence\n");
  gets(str1); 

  while(str1[k]!='\0') {

     j=0; 
     while(str1[k]!=' '&&str1[k]!='\0') {
       substr[i][j]=str1[k]; 
       k++; j++;
     }

     substr[i][j]='\0';
     i++;
     if(str1[k]!='\0') { 
        k++;
     }
   } 

   long int len=i;
   max=strlen(substr[0]);
   min=strlen(substr[0]);

   for(i=0;i<len;i++) { 
      a=strlen(substr[i]);
      if(a>max) {
         max=a; maxIndex=i;
       }
      if(a<min) { 
         min=a; minIndex=i;
      }
   }

   printf("Largest Word is %s \nSmallest word is %s\n",substr[maxIndex],substr[minIndex]);

}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add your code there using coding-style

Comment: Also, what is "common" in this context? Most naturally occuring? Or being the same as letters in the found words?

Comment: @MaximPlaton please [edit] your question and show example of input and expected output.

Comment: @MrLister meaning edit??

Comment: @MrLister can i write in fb?if you have

Comment: What if the sentence has multiple words of the same shortest, or longest length, What if the shortest and longest word(s) have no characters in common?  What if all of the words are the same length?  Address these, and any other problem descriptions by editing them into your post _WITH_ some examples of input you might use, and the expected output.

Comment: @MaximPlaton Does my solution work for you?

Comment: @AkashDas, example: Input: This is Isomorphic.  Output : smallest word is: "is", Longest word is: "Isomorphic".  Common letters for smallest and longest word is: i ,s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `printf` at the end of your code and add the following lines to your code before closing the `main()` method.

```
   int common[26] = {0};

   for(i = 0; i < strlen(substr[minIndex]); i++)
   {
       for(j = 0; j < strlen(substr[maxIndex]); j++)
       {
           if(tolower(substr[maxIndex][j]) == tolower(substr[minIndex][i]))
           {
               common[tolower(substr[minIndex][i]) - 'a'] = 1;
           }
       }
   }

   for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
   {
       if(common[i] == 1)
       {
            printf("%c\n", (i + 'a'));
       }
   }
```

What this does is, it compares every letter in the longest word with every letter in the shortest word and for every match, it marks the corresponding index in `common` alphabets array as `1`. After all the letters have been traversed through, we simply iterate through the `common` array and print the marked letters.

Full working code below:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h> 

int main() {

  long int i=0,j=0,k=0,a,minIndex=0,maxIndex=0,max=0,min=0;
  char str1[100]={0},substr[100][100]={0};

  printf("Enter a sentence\n");
  gets(str1); 

  while(str1[k]!='\0') {

     j=0; 
     while(str1[k]!=' '&&str1[k]!='\0') {
       substr[i][j]=str1[k]; 
       k++; j++;
     }

     substr[i][j]='\0';
     i++;
     if(str1[k]!='\0') { 
        k++;
     }
   } 

   long int len=i;
   max=strlen(substr[0]);
   min=strlen(substr[0]);

   for(i=0;i<len;i++) { 
      a=strlen(substr[i]);
      if(a>max) {
         max=a; maxIndex=i;
       }
      if(a<min) { 
         min=a; minIndex=i;
      }
   }

   printf("The longest word is: %s \nThe shortest word is: %s\n",substr[maxIndex],substr[minIndex]);

   int common[26] = {0};

   for(i = 0; i < strlen(substr[minIndex]); i++)
   {
       for(j = 0; j < strlen(substr[maxIndex]); j++)
       {
           if(tolower(substr[maxIndex][j]) == tolower(substr[minIndex][i]))
           {
               common[tolower(substr[minIndex][i]) - 'a'] = 1;
           }
       }
   }

   printf("Common letters between the longest word and the shortest word are:  ");

   for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
   {
       if(common[i] == 1)
       {
            printf("%c, ", (i + 'a'));
       }
   }
   printf("\b\b ");   
}
```

**INPUT**

```
This is Isomorphic
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The longest word is: Isomorphic 
The shortest word is: is
Common letters between the longest word and the shortest word are:  i, s
```

Comment: This is a good solution. You could sort the letters to give `O(n log n)` instead of `O(n^2)`, and the universe of 26 letters could be expanded into a hash map if needed.

Comment: @Neil That's would be a good optimized approach. There were no constraints mentioned in the OP's question. Hence, I went for a simpler approach, skimping out on optimization.

Comment: @AkashDas thank you very much , but where to add 'printf' for smallest and longest word?i need this printf.

Comment: @AkashDas , your code is right , but according to your code smallest word is "is" , not ,,This" , a tried to compile but words with one , two letters not recognizes that they are small.

Comment: can you help me please? @AkashDas

Comment: @AkashDas, example: Input: This is Isomorphic. Output : smallest word is: "is", Longest word is: "Isomorphic". Common letters for smallest and longest word is: i ,s.

Comment: @MaximPlaton I have changed the code to suit your required output format. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @MaximPlaton Cheers mate. :)